# On the measurability of stochastic integrals

Tags: stochastic-calculus, measurable-functions

Let $S(t)$ be a $C_0$-contraction semi-group, $W$ is a cylindrical Wiener process in a separate Hilbert space $U$. Assume the following conditions:
$$
\|F(t,u_1)-F(t,u_2)\|_{H}<  C\|u_1-u_2\|_{H},~~\|F(t,u)\|_{H}<  C(1+\|u\|_{H}).
$$
$$
\|G(t,u_1)-F(t,u_2)\|_{L_2(U,H)}<  C\|u_1-u_2\|_{H},~~\|G(t,u)\|_{L_2(U,H)}<  C(1+\|u\|_{H}).
$$
Now we consider the mild solution to above equation in the form of
$$
u(t)=S(t)u_0+\int_0^tS(t-s)F(s,u)\,dt+\int_0^tS(t-s) G(s,u) \, dW_s. \tag 1
$$
**My question**:

1. If $u$ is progressively measurable, are the deterministic and stochastic integrals on the right hand side of (1) also progressively measurable?
2. In many books, the author proved the existence and uniqueness of predictable solution. How can we prove the well-posedness of a progressively measurable solution?